# Node.js: File reading and putting string as array into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, file, node.js

I'm working on some project where I need to read some fle and put splitted (with \n - new line) string as array in array. This means that the output from reading file with `fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8').split('\n');`
is string and I need to convert it into array, but there is problem because I don't know how. There is some example of input data:

```
[[164,17567,160,[]],[166,8675,103,[]],
[[164,17567,160,[]],[166,8675,103,[]],
[[164,17567,160,[]],[166,8675,103,[]],
[[164,17567,160,[]],[166,8675,103,[]]
```

I was trying to put it with for loop, but I can't convert it from string into array somehow, the output becomes like that:

```
"[[164,17567,160,[]],[166,8675,103,[]]",
"[[164,17567,160,[]],[166,8675,103,[]]",
"[[164,17567,160,[]],[166,8675,103,[]]",
"[[164,17567,160,[]],[166,8675,103,[]]"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest that you carry on splitting by newline, then recombine into a single string without the line breaks, then finally parse using JSON.parse.

```
var lines = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8').split('\n');
var rawData = '';
for (var l in lines){
    var line = lines[l];
    rawdata += line;
}
var data = JSON.parse('[' + rawdata + ']');
```

However! It appears (unless it's a typo) that each line there is an extra opening square bracket. These must be deleted before parsing, preferably from the source data if you have any control over it :)

In addition, to make it valid JSON, you will have to wrap the whole thing in "[ ]" as I have shown above.

Comment: `var data = require(filepath);` does the same trick for .json files.

Comment: I have already tried to parse it, but then this function drop some objects from array. At the end parsed array become a list of numbers serperated with comma.

Comment: I've tried to improve the answer based on your comment, please have a look